# check and insert email to db and call ajax if email already exist alert user

Tags: php, ajax, database, email, insert

Hello i have following code.
the thing i'm trying to do is when user enters email it should check to db if it already exist. if the email dose not exist then store it in database and send it to ajax function

```
    <!-- Begin  Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">

<form>

  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="required email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" style="font-size:15pt;height:38px;width:350px;font-family:Century Gothic;margin-right:5px;" >

  <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text" name="b_438e8df85b7f9df7fce94287a_013c74a5bc" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
  <button value="Submit" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="button" style="background-color: rgba(14,46,71,1);border: 1px solid #0E2E47;width:150px;height:37px;font-family:Century Gothic;font-size:18px;color:white;">Subscribe</button>
  <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
    <div class="response" id="error" style="display:none"></div>
    <div class="response" id="success" style="display:none"></div>
  </div>
</form>

</div>
<!--End mc_embed_signup-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function call_mailm(){

  $.ajax({url: "https://google.co.in/account/mailserverprimary/"+$("#email").val(), 
    success: function(result){
      $('#mc_embed_signup').html('<div align="center"  style="color:#0E2E47;font-size:18px;font-family:Century Gothic;">Thank you for subscribing.</div>');

    },
    error: function (error) {
      alert("Please Enter Valid Email Address.");
    }
  });
  return false;

}
</script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var re = /(\w+)\@(\w+)\.[a-zA-Z]/g;
    var $email = $("#email");
        $('#mc_embed_signup form').submit(function(){

            var emailValue = $email.val();
            var testEmail = re.test(emailValue);

            if(!testEmail){
                alert("Please enter valid email address.");
                $email.focus();
            } else {
                call_mailm();
            }

            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my php

```
<?php           
         $host = 'localhost';
         $user = 'root';
         $pass = '123';

         mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

         mysql_select_db('dummy_test');


         if(isset($_POST['email']))
         {
           $emailId=$_POST['email'];

           $checkdata=" SELECT loginid FROM user WHERE loginid='$emailId' ";

           $query=mysql_query($checkdata);

           if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
           {
             echo "Email Already Exist";
           }
           else
           {
             if( isset( $_POST['submit_form'] ) )
{

$email = $_POST['email'];


$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '123';

mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

mysql_select_db('dummy_test');

$insertdata=" INSERT INTO user VALUES( '$email' ) ";
mysql_query($insertdata);
           }

?>
```

Unfortunetly i dont know how to integrate php with form and ajax
Any suggestions would be appreciate... thank you

Comment: then whats your problem

Comment: it dose not work please help me to make it

Comment: please check you url for ajax call

Comment: that's the dummy url (removed for misuse)